# How to prevent Texter/PhraseExpress from causing misfired KeyUp events in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, keyboard

I have a VB.NET application. When **Texter** or **PhraseExpress** is installed and enabled, the program behaves poorly. Debugging has revealed that at times I can press Enter in a field and no event will be fired (i.e. no breakpoints in the event handlers get hit), then I press it again, and they will be fired twice. (Basically these cycle if I keep pressing enter - one time nothing will happen, the next I get two events, the next keypress does nothing, the next triggers two events, etc.)

Since Enter is used in certain places to trigger searches, or to move between fields for fast data entry using the numeric keypad, this effectively breaks the program in these spots.

The problem is highly repeatable - disabling Texter or PhraseExpress causes the program behaves perfectly normally. Enabling them again causes it to break.

Note that in both text expansion programs, I have assigned NO events to the Enter key. In fact, with Texter (haven't done this particular test with PE yet), it happens even if NO replacements have been defined at all, simply based on whether Texter is enable or disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PhraseExpress, please disable the expert option "Route TAB and ENTER through PhraseExpress" if you experience problems those keys.

Screenshot:

[image]

Please also note that using multipe Text Expander simultaneously may introduce interferences as you experienced. Unfortunately, there is no way to get around this limitation for us vendors.

Michael Schmidt
PhraseExpress Team

Comment: Thanks! I have not installed multiple text expanders, I tried Tester first, then we tried Phrase Express on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to events by overriding ProcessDialogKey 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey.aspx
 instead of attaching to the control's event directly.